# Factoring complex polynomials in polar form

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question regarding factoring a polynomial with complex roots and representing the answer in polar form.
Take this polynomial:
$$
(1)\phantom{........}z^2 + 4z +16 = 0
$$
I have roots of
$$
(2)\phantom{........}z=-2 \pm 2 \sqrt{3}i
$$

So in polar representation I have
$$
(3)\phantom{.........}z=4e^{\pm 2\pi i/3}
$$

The question I have is to find next the roots of

$$
(4)\phantom{.........}z^4 +4z^2 +16=0
$$

I am unsure how finding the previous roots helps with finding the roots for the next eq. Thanks for all help and suggestions!

Comment: You need to find the roots of of $(z^2)^2+4(z^2)+16$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $z^2 \to t$ you have $t^2 + 4t + 16 = 0$. (remember that $z^4 = (z^2)^2$) Do you know where to go from there?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps let $z^2=u$, hence $z^4+4z^2+16 = u^2+4u^2+16$ and then use your original method to obtain the roots, and substitute the $z$ values back in.